# Set text background color in android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-edittext

I want to set text background color not whole background of `TextView`. I want do this in Android. So how can I do this?

**For example:**
'TEXT' a background of 'TEXT' is colored. After that background color is default.
I don't set whole background color.(android:background="") Not this. android:background gives TextViews background color.I want Texts background color.

Comment: did you mean text selection color?

Comment: Sanju, please can you accept the correct answer!! We need to know which answer was correct for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the attribute style="@style/your_style" that is defined for any widget.

to define your style you have to create a file called your_style.xml in the values folder and use the following syntax

```
 <style name="You.EditText.Style" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
     <item name="android:background">@color/textbackgroundcolor</item>  
 </style>
```

this attribute parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText" is important cause it will make the style your are defining extend the basic android EditText style so that you will have only to override the attributes you want to change

Answer (score 1):

setBackgroundResource(R.color.WhateverColorYouLike);

Answer (score 0):

you can set the background color of your `EditText` like this :

```
myEditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.blue);
```

width and height of the EditText must be `WRAP_CONTENT`

Comment: I got  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xff000000
            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1015)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:660)
            at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:14265)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the attribute android:textColor="BLUE_HEX_VALUE" in whatever TextViews you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use android:textColor="#xxxxxx" in your xml file to change ONLY TEXT color